# Travis CI deployment from GitHub to Azure returns ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (shallow update not allowed)

Tags: node.js, git, azure, github, travis-ci

I am trying to deploy a simple NodeJS website using Travis CI to Azure.

I have followed all the steps outlined in this article: https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2015/09/30/using-travis-ci-to-deploy-to-azure/

This is the repo (public): https://github.com/mizrael/barfer .

The build process is fine, typescript files are correctly transpiled and all the tests pass.

Unfortunately, when it comes to the final deployment stage, which I guess it's pushing the changes to the Local Git repo set on the Azure Web App, I get this error :

**! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (shallow update not allowed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://[secure]:[secure]@barfer.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/barfer.git'**

Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

nevermind, seems I managed to find how to fix this by adding this

```
git:
   depth: 9999999
```

to the *.travis.yml* configuration file.